# Illegal parameter number in definition of \book code

Tags: memoir, books

I am trying to produce a PDF of the bible from: https://github.com/vermiculus/bible so that I can add some notes.

Running pdflatex on bible.tex gives me the following error:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \book code.  
>                      3 l.55 }

(full error here: https://hastebin.com/erikixeqan.nginx )

I tried removing all non-header code from the bible.tex file and it gives the same error, and even the **same line number**, despite their being less than 55 lines total. My suspicion is the bible.cls file, because of the full error text.

That said, there are no definitions in bible.cls at line 55, and usages of \book are few. Here are all instances of 'book' in bible.cls:

```
Line 19: \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\@ifundefined{@currbook}{}{\@currbook}}
Line 19: \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\@ifundefined{@currbook}{}{\@currbook}}
Line 27: %\newcounter{book}
Line 28: \setcounter{book}{0}
Line 31: \DeclareDocumentCommand{\book}{om}{
Line 36:   % Step the book counter
Line 37:   \refstepcounter{book}
Line 39:   % define book key (used in notes)
Line 40:   \edef\@currbook{\IfNoValueTF{#3}{#2}{#3}}
Line 42:   % Don't display page numbers on pages that list a book
Line 121: \newcommand{\testbook}[1]{\def\inputbook@only{#1}}
Line 121: \newcommand{\testbook}[1]{\def\inputbook@only{#1}}
Line 124: \newcommand{\inputbook}[1]{
Line 127:     \cs_if_exist:NTF{\inputbook@only}
Line 128:       {\IfStrEq{#1}{\inputbook@only}{\input{\bibleversion/#1}\clearpage}}
```

By googling the error I found posts hinting that defining a macro/command inside another can cause errors in specific scenarios, so line 121 looks the most suspicious to me.

I'd like to find out what definition has gone awry, (perhaps by latex simply growing/changing?)

I apologize if I haven't been clear. I've been programming a few years, using latex for some months, but haven't gone very deep.

Comment: Lines 121 and 122 look OK. My guess is 128.

Comment: If you look at `bible.cls` in GitHub, line 55 is the end of the definition of `\DeclareDocumentCommand{\book}{om}` that starts on line 31. My knowledge of Latex3 is close to zilch, but it looks like the `{om}` is declaring 2 parameters, but the definition uses 3. In other words, the error message might just mean what it says - no creative interpretation required!

Comment: @alephzero Hmm. Moving around the definition does change the line of the error to the new end of the declare statement each time!  

All I did was add an additional optional argument in the header, making line 32: ` \DeclareDocumentCommand{\book}{omo}{` and it works! 

Looks like this document was created back when arguments defaulting to other arguments wasn't supported.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @sudom82 Yes, that's the only possible fix.

Comment: I should probably update this repository... :-)

Comment: @alephzero Could you make that a comment? Or perhaps sudom82 might write something up?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.